# DropDownExtender Clickable Arrow Issue

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

In my current project I am adding a DropDownExtender (from the AJAX toolkit) to my DropDownList. I am doing this to improve the look of the drop down. My code looks something like this (list items are populated at run time):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" 
                  runat="server"/>
<act:DropDownExtender TargetControlID="dropdown1"
                      id="DropDownExtender1" 
                      runat="server"/>
```

The drop down works; however, in order to access the list items in the drop down, I have to click the actual text area/box of the drop down. Clicking the arrow will not work. Any ideas/suggestions on how to get this to work correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to put your drop down extender into a panel.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=167

check this code out here

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2009/12/ajax-dropdownextender-how-to-use.html

Comment: I followed a few tutorials and they showed this method of implementing the DropDownExtender with a panel etc... but is there no other way to get it to work ontop of a regular DropDownList?

Comment: Im pretty sure you have to use a panel, the ajax click event is usually located in that panel. I modified my answer.